# Не появляется текст

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть 6 блоков. Внутри них 2 картинки,заголовок текста и сам текст (у которого по-молчанию display:none ), его id #st. Когда я навожу на див, текст должен появляться, но этого не происходит.

```js
$("#tab").hover(function(){
  $(this).$("#st").css("display","block");
},function(){
  $(this).$("#st").css("display","none");
});
```

```css
.pure-u-1-3{
  width:25%;
  margin-left:5%;
  padding:10px;
  z-index:1;
}
.pure-u-1-3 string{
  display:none;
  font-family: 'Roboto Light',arial;
  font-size:12pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pure-u-1-3" id="tab">
 <img src="images/success.png" height="82"  width="81" alt="">
 <img src="images/arrow.png" class='i-m-g' height="16" width="20" alt="">
 <div class="wh">Утверждение формата сотрудничества</div>
 <string id="st">В период подготовки проекта, компанией-заказчиком предоставляется техническое задание и перечень требований к выполнению работы. При наличие исходной базы данных – она также передается для ознакомления.</string>
</div>
```

Comment: Уберите `$(this)` в JS, оно там лишнее и не к чему.

Comment: @AlexKrass у меня 6 таких блоков

Comment: Для нескольких блоков использовать одинаковые id запрещено, поменяйте их на классы.

Comment: @pride для выборки из контекста используется другой синтаксис [JQuery Core](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/): `$("#st", this)`. Но это не отменяет того факта, что ID должен быть уникальным для страницы, как уже сказали используйте классы.

Comment: @AlexKrass, либо использовать `find`

Answer (score 3):

Если заглянуть в консоль браузера, то можно обнаружить следующую ошибку:

```
TypeError: $(...).$ is not a function
```

Что неудивительно, потому что у jQuery-объектов (в данном случае это объект `$(this)`) функции $ конечно же нет.

Достаточно просто получить объект по селектору, написав так:

```
$("#tab").hover(function(){
  $("#st").css("display","block");
},function(){
  $("#st").css("display","none");
});
```

Но вообще для этого ни js, ни тем более jQuery не нужны: всё это превосходно делается средствами CSS:

```
#tab #st {display: none;}
#tab:hover #st {display: block;}
```

Comment: у меня есть 6 таких блоков. Код который вы предложили, я тестировал и текст появляется только у первого блока

Comment: буду благодарен если напишете css код

Comment: @pride Это уже должен быть совсем другой вопрос

Comment: поправил вопрос

Comment: @pride, это все потому, что id элемента, должен быть **уникальным** на странице.

Comment: а как поступить тогда

Comment: @pride, не использовать одинаковые id, либо сделать их разными, либо использовать классы

Answer (score 1):

Средствами CSS:

```
#tab #st {display: none;}
#tab:hover #st {display: block;}
```

Или если хотите использовать JS тогда это:

```
$("#tab").hover(function(){
  $(this).find("#st").show();
},function(){
  $(this).find("#st").hide();
});
```

Функция find ищет дочерние элементы с #st